# how to remove Error: [ng:areq] with angularjs in MVC..?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive

how to remove Error with angularjs in MVC..?!

[image]

i'm creating a web app in angularjs MVC
i have add all the reference for angular script files
i write code in separate javascript file as AdminController.js, i have also referenced it on view, but i'm not able to trigger angularjs controller's method on the view.

my AdminCtrl.js code is as:

```
 var adminModule = angular.module('angApp', []);
//Defining a Angular Controller
adminModule.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
//Retrieving the List of people
Login();
function Login(U_Name, U_PWD) {
    //Defining the $http service for login the admin user
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Models/AdminModels',
        data: {User_Name:U_Name,User_PWD:U_PWD}
    }).success(function (result) {

        if (result == true){
            alert('user is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('unauthorised access!');
        }
    })
          }
}]);
```

please suggest me for the best option so that i can perform my task,

thanks in advance.

Comment: now i have another issue with ng-repeat
it's not firing on view, i'm getting result on console but not on view, would you like to help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your ng-repeat code and data please, is the data in $scope ?

Comment: var adminModule = angular.module('angApp', []);
adminModule.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        //*****get data from  Product table
        $scope.products = {};
        GetAdmin();
        function GetAdmin() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Admin/GetAdmin',
                datatype:'HTML',
            }).success(function data() {
                $scope.products = data.result;
            })
        }
    }]);


it is my AdminCtrl.js code here i'm getting data and able to get it on console

Comment: <div id="divTest" ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in products">
            Prod_ID:{{item.Prod_ID}}
            Prod_Name:{{item.Prod_Name}}
            Prod_Price:{{item.Prod_Price}}
            Prod_Desc:{{item.Prod_Desc}}
        </div>
        </div>

this is my view code where i want to bind data using ng-repeat but it's not working for me 

plz help me to fix this issue.

Comment: first of all, the data are displayed with this ? :   <div id="divTest" ng-controller="AdminCtrl"> {{products}} </div>

Comment: {{products}} is not single entity it return collection & i'm writing code to fetch data from it using ng-repeat

would you like to provide me your Gtalk id

Comment: i'm able to get this data on Console when i'm getting this data on view using $scope this time it doesn't work

Comment: even if products is an array when you put {{products}} in the view it should display the array. if it dont display anythink so your view is not linked to the controller. 

try this : plnkr.co/edit/jTWWoJaS6FVdtZuOqVgR

Comment: also i'm not sure about http get syntaxe. is use this : 
$http.get("http://yourUrl/service").success(function(data) { $scope.products = data; });

Comment: @AlainIb i'm able to see data in alert but issue only with binding data using ng-repeat

Comment: ok
did you look at the html code of this for: http://plnkr.co/edit/jTWWoJaS6FVdtZuOqVgR?p=preview ? 
maybe your data is not formatted well to match the ng-repeat. in your controller, in the http call put this line : console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));  and past the resutlt from the console pleas

Comment: yes, it's working fine but what mistake i'm doing in application i couldn't get

Comment: please run this and paste the data from your console 
function GetAdmin() {
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Admin/GetAdmin', datatype:'HTML', }).success(
  function data() { 
     $scope.products = data.result; 
     console.log("---";
     console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.products, undefined, 2));
     console.log("---";
  }
 ) 
}

Comment: it is not displaying data on console

Comment: your http call il maybe wrong. did you try this instead ?
$http.get("/Admin/GetAdmin").success(function(data) { $scope.products = data; console.log($scope.products);});

Comment: great. and in the html did the data displayed with <pre> {{products|json}} ?

Comment: the ng-repeat too ? if not paste the displayed data

Comment: yes, ng-repeat directive is also working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did only a little bit mistake, i was binding ng-app to  but in the sense it should be bind with  now it's working.

my new code like as  .....

```
   <body ng-app="angApp">
   <script src="Scripts/app/AdminCtrl.js"></script>

   <div id="alert" class="alert"></div>
   <div ng-controller="AdminCtrl">

        <div class="admin-login">
            <h2>using angularjs</h2>
            <input type="text" id="txtUserAng" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="U_Name" />
            <input type="password" id="txtPWDAng" placeholder="Password" ng-model="U_PWD" />
            <input type="button" id="login" value="login" ng-click="Login()" />

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```